# Change the location of labels from a plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to change the location of the graph labels from the top right corner to the botton right corner.

```
funnel.plot(x="date_event_nk", y=["Show_Start", "Start_Complete"], kind="bar")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
funnel.legend(loc='lower right')
```